# "No decoder available for type 'video/x-h264

Tags: qt, qt4, centos7, gstreamer

I am running qt video player I made but every time I load a mp4 file or mp3 it gives me this error.
MP4:

```
Warning: "No decoder available for type 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)2.1, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, codec_data=(buffer)0142c015ffe100176742c015da06025b011000000300100000030320f162ea01000468ce3c80, width=(int)384, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, parsed=(boolean)true'."
Error: "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in."
```

MP3:

```
Warning: "No decoder available for type 'audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, mpegaudioversion=(int)1, layer=(int)3, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2, parsed=(boolean)true'."
Error: "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in."
```

By the way I am on Centos 7.9.2009 core if that has to do with anything

Comment: The error message seems fairly self-explanatory.  You need to find and install the gstreamer plugins that provide the required codecs.  You might want to refer to [this list](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins_doc.html?gi-language=c).

Comment: According to centos I have already installed every gstreamer plugin and I recompiled the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that media programs should be compiled on windows. Or if your really dedicated to it, include every .h file for gstreamer in your program and carry around those files everywhere the program goes